# How to get nearest 5 points mean with Nearest Neighbours?

Tags: scikit-learn, k-nn

In a dataset of **longitude**, **latitude** and **price** (of houses) I'm using sklearn's KNearestRegressor to get the 5 nearest neighbors **mean price** for each point. The problem is I want to do this for the whole dataset and each point is taking its own price into consideration since KNearestRegressor is a supervised algorithm, and I'm predicting the training set. How can I get the 5 nearest neighbors mean price for each point, not taking into consideration that point's price?

I have tried sklearn's unsupervised NearestNeighbours but it only outputs the indexes of the nearest neighbors, not the mean price.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you train/ fit a model on the training set, may be cross validate using a training set. But it is not meant to predict itself. That's what test set is for.

You can achieve your objective by predicting each observation in a Leave One Out manner (also used for cross validation):

For every observation (i) in your dataset, fit a KNN regressor using all data except (i), evaluate your prediction for (i).